# How I can get realtime OpenCV current frame even I lost time in processing?

Tags: opencv, c++11, image-processing

We are processing images from camera through opencv. Processing took more than frame per second. I can process almost 4 or 3 images per second.

I leaves me behind the current frame , I always get the cache fram next in the queue.

How can I get the current frame always ?

we are using c++11

Comment: google about _multithreading_

Answer (score 1):

Use one thread for capture and one for processing. The processing thread should get a copy of the current image from the capture thread.
Don't forget to use appropriate synchronization when copying the image.

If the capture thread stores the images, you may process the dropped images later.